# Testing hypothesis in R

Tags: r, statistical-significance

I have the following two datasets which represent the mean absolute error generated by two models.

```
> dput(modelA)
c(13.3739, 42.82576, 52.25314, 22.19749, 58.82374, 149.18636, 33.92114, 53.193423, 60.10674, 65.912029)

> dput(modelB)
c(23.40096, 73.827, 104.83493, 56.81481, 66.9312, 183.0849, 79.69471, 
58.35022, 64.08333, 48.38391)
```

It can clearly be seen that error produced by modelA is smaller than modelB. I want to statistically prove in R by considering a NULL HYPOTHESIS (H0) that modelA does not produce lesser error than modelB. I will prefer student's t-test. How can I do it R?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you ever wonder "how can I do <commonly used model> in R?", 99% of the times you can enter the search query "r <commonly used model>" in Google and you'll find the answer at the top. For example, searching  for "r t-test" in Google gives the answer you seek. Also, the mathematical-statistics tag is not appropriate for your question.

Comment: I searched alot but I couldnot find anything relative to my problem. It would be kind if you can guide me to a link :)

Comment: like I said... Google "r t-test" and you shall receive.

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach is to compute the difference between the two vectors and then run a one-sided t-test for paired observations like

```
modelA <- c(13.3739, 42.82576, 52.25314, 22.19749, 58.82374, 149.18636, 33.92114, 53.193423, 60.10674, 65.912029)
modelB <- c(23.40096, 73.827, 104.83493, 56.81481, 66.9312, 183.0849, 79.69471, 58.35022, 64.08333, 48.38391)

t.test(modelB-modelA, alternative = "greater")
```

Why might this approach be naive?

1. Why are you testing a one-sided alternative? Would you have changed its direction if model B would have been better than model A? So probably a two-sided approach is more appropriate.
2. A small-sample t-test assumes normality (among other stuff). We don't know if this is the case, so a non-parametric test like the Wilcoxon sign-rank test might be better.
3. If your errors come from a training data set which you used to derive model A and model B, then maybe model A is only better due to some overfitting issue. In such a case the method is only appropriate with fresh, untouched validation data.

Comment: Thankyou Michael.
So in R it will go like;


wilcox.test(modelB-modelA, alternative = "greater")

Comment: Yes, if e.g. non-normality is the only problem.